# Create authentication system for model other than User in Django

Tags: django

I have a model called `Company`. I want to add the functionalities of `User` model such as `password` field and `register` and `login` for that `Company` model. I know to extend built-in `User` model for the purposes of `User` model. How can I get the similar authentication and other `User` model functionalities to the `Company` model in `Django`?

Answer (score 0):

Does your question mean that you want to use `Company` model in django authentication like as the `User` model in default? You can do by simply adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.Company'` into settings.py. Refer to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Yes and also I would like to retain the authentication for `User` model. Both models require the authentication functionalities.

Comment: I'm still not very much clear about your question but, creating `Company` model as a subclass of `User` can help you? In this case 'AUTH_USER_MODEL' should be set as `User`.

Comment: Yes. Creating `Company` class as a suclass helps. Your answer also helps. I'm asking what if I want authentication for both `User` and `Company` classes separately? Separate `login` and `register` for both. Separate tables and authentication functionality separately.

Comment: Now I'm clear but I find I don't have the answer, sorry. Let us wait for another answer...

Comment: Ok. No problem. Your answer made me know the method to change the name of the `User` model.